# Firefox vs Chrome CSS padding and margin difference

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I'm having issues with my CSS. There's a gap under my icons in Firefox, but not in Chrome. I'm really confused about where the issue is coming from.

Screenshot of Firefox footer: http://puu.sh/dqkrp/1ca27fd502.png
 
Screenshot of Chrome footer: http://puu.sh/dqkOw/ea7749b56c.png

```
<footer>
  <div id="contact-bar">
   ...
  </div>
</footer>

#contact-bar {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:right;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#contact-bar ul {
    margin:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: auto;
    float:right;
}

#contact-bar ul li{
    float:right;
}

#contact-bar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}   

footer {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
        clear:both;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: use the dev tools in firefox to inspect the element.  When all else fails use Normalize.css

Comment: or use `*{margin:0; padding:0;}`

Comment: It could simply be the images themselves. By default the images are `display: inline` and `vertical-align: baseline`. This causes a gap at the bottom of the image which is pushing down the images parent. If this is causing the gap, then you can use either `#contact-bar img {
  display: block;
}` to make them block elements OR `#contact-bar img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}` to change the default vertical alignment.

Comment: Normalize your CSS using some normalize.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the exact issue was with the difference between the footer in Chrome and Firefox, but I set the height of the footer to exactly 27px, which is the height of the icons, to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Every browser has its own predefined styling for the HTML tags. Because of this if we have not specified a style for an element it is possible that different browser will have different style for that element.

The most popular way of overcoming this is to use css reset style sheet which will override all the default styling of the browser. Then we can no longer worry about different padding and margins in various browsers.

As far I know Eric Meyers reset styling is the most popular among the reset styles

Below is the url for the css code
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Just copy the content in this page and add it in to your css. This should resolve your problem.

On looking closely at your css i think there is one more problem which i think could cause this issue: Please change padding :auto; padding:0px; like below

```
#contact-bar ul {
    margin:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0px !important;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: @Soubriquet Can you please try my updated option. auto is not a valid value for the padding property. I think it would be better if you post your complete markup(just the semantics) which would help drill down this issue.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has its own default styles. Reset them by putting this at the very top of your css file:

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, em, img, strong, sub, sup, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, section, time {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. :/

Comment: @Soubriquet I'm not able to replicate your problem with the code you've provided. Can you create a jsfiddle to show the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Browser have there own properties by default as sometimes images have border in IE like that chrome and mozila applies there margin and padding try to make it 0

```
ul,li{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```